# Can we migrate SharePoint 2010 web portal to Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, office365, sharepoint-online

Hi I have a SharePoint Farm Solution developed in SharePoint 2010, We have a requirement to migrate it from SharePoint 2010 to office 365. 
Is it possible to migrate it without any difficulty or it is not recommended to migrate SharePoint 2010 to Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly use the farm solution in office 365, as Farm solutions are not supported in office 365/SharePoint Online. Please see this reference link: https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/232435

You will have to transform the farm solution in app model and then you will get the same functionality in office 365.

[Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn986827.aspx) to see more about the transformation of Farm solutions to App Model.

**Note:** It's not mandatory that you use Apps only for this. You can use other approaches as well i.e. JSOM, OOTB etc.. It depends on the functionality of your farm solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response Hemant, but if i say that my SharePoint 2010 solution is a custom solution. The workflows are of SharePoint designer. And it i think it would take lots of effort to convert my farm solution into app model. So what you suggest should I migrate it to office 365 or not ?

Comment: I believe that it depends on the business requirement. Based on efforts, do you want to migrate it or not, it should be a decision of stakeholders or company. It's not mandatory that you go with App Model only. If your requirement is achievable OOTB then you can go with this as well.

Comment: And if i forget about migration, and start from scratch development on office 365, is it recommended to develop custom solutions on office 365. the project is completely customized and we need to develop some workflow as well. How much does Office 365 supports custom development ?

Comment: Yes, Custom development is fully supported by Office 365. As Custom Development you can create SharePoint Apps and also you can create SharePoint Designer Workflows as per your requirement. There are lot more options for Custom development like CSOM, JSOM, REST API etc., which you can use for your custom development.

Comment: Here I am sharing some reference links, hope these links will help you..
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Plan-customizations-solutions-and-apps-for-SharePoint-Online-b7898ebf-69b7-4196-81e3-b04e1a4e7d67
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/custom-development-using-sharepoint-online-on-office-365